# How to Bootstrap these elements

Tags: javascript, html, css, meteor, twitter-bootstrap-3

This may seem weird, I want to create a header as simple as this of Stack Overflow so I've been struggling writing the right codes.

```
<template name="DashboardLayout">
<hr>
    <div class="row">
        <div col-md-8 col-md-offset-9><center><input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search.."></center> </div>
        <div col-md-4 ><center><label>Profile</label></center> </div>
        <div col-md-4 ><center><label>Settings</label></center> </div>
        <div col-md-4 ><center><label>Videos</label></center> </div>
        <div col-md-4 ><center><div class="dropdown">
          <div class="dropbtn">Dropdown</div>
          <div class="dropdown-content">
            <a href="#">Link 1</a>
            <a href="#">Link 2</a>
            <a href="#">Link 3</a>
          </div>
        </div></center> </div>
    </div>
<hr>
</template>
```

How can I achieve this using Bootstrap?

Comment: <template> isn't an html tag and <center> is old. deprecated

Comment: I'm using meteor js blaze template. Thanks for this.

Comment: edit hang on a min.

Answer (score 0):

What are you asking for ? to give you the full HTML CSS and JS is needed ?

[Check this link in Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-default) the default example es basically what you want.
 Logo, links (text or icon links), search bar and dropdown.
 All responsive.

Then just play around the styles to get a better copy of this.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is add some custom classes for existing tags and write your own styles for corresponding classes. 
or If you need simple customised version of this you can use [this](http://bootstrapdesigntools.com/tools/bootstrap-menu-builder/) to build it easier 
or this one https://work.smarchal.com/twbscolor/

read [this](http://blog.jetstrap.com/2013/07/less-like-bootstrap/) if you want even mature look for your nav bar http://blog.jetstrap.com/2013/07/less-like-bootstrap/